# Передача элемента страницы в объект

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп, объекты

Как передать моему объекту элемент страницы для дальнейших манипуляций с ним внутри этого же объекта ?

Ниже привёл не рабочий пример для дополнительной ясности в вопрос:

```
var elem = {
    foo: $('#a'),

    bar: function(){
        this.foo.text('aabbcc');
    }
}

elem.bar();
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGONbJ ваш пример работает. Возможно в момент присвоения в foo элемента #a еще нет в DOM?

Comment: Наверное,да, мне нужно посмотреть, спасибо, как-то забыл про это

Comment: Действительно работает, наверное нужно завязывать с ночным кодингом:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что вы хотите сделать что-то вроде [своего плагина](http://habrahabr.ru/post/158235/).

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.bar = function() {
    var foo = function() {
      $(this).text('New text');
    };
    return this.each(foo);
  };

}(jQuery));

$('.el').bar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el">Old text</div>
<div class="other_el">Other element</div>
<div class="el">Old text</div>
```

Comment: Это мой второй вопрос на который я хотел узнать ответ, но не знал как его изложить, спасибо и вам большое